# Battery packs constuction

Tags: voltage

I am going away for 6 months to a place where there is limited electricity supply. All I want to do is construct a battery pack using truck batteries, I then want to connect this to the hardwiring of a house. I want to know if this is safe and how to complete this battery pack. People there do use one battery connected to a transformer and just plugged into a socket. That charges the battery whilst there is electric and when the electric goes off the battery powers the house through the same socket but the battery only lasts an hour or two on limited output. I want to have a battery that will see me through several hours of fans going, air con going and fridge freezer and lights running.

Comment: What is the power consumption of all the appliances turned on?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be impractical.

### Power requirements and batteries

An air-conditioning (A/C) unit might be rated at 3kW and run on 230 volts (V) alternating current (AC). To draw that power from a 12 V direct-current (DC) truck battery requires a current of 250 Amps (3000/12). That's a **very** high continuous current. Normally the heaviest load on an automotive battery is the starter-motor which draws much less current and for shorter periods. The battery voltage will drop by several volts with high current. If you have a 140 Ah battery it could last just over half an hour (140/250) but towards the end of that period the voltage will drop to an unusably low level. To last five hours you'd need more than twenty batteries.

You should do the sums with a generator and a two-thousand litre tank of fuel, full of fuel, to see if it is cheaper and more reliable.

### DC AC conversion

To convert 12V DC from the batteries to 120 or 230V AC for the A/C you'd need an inverter.

To switch between the normal supply and your invertor you'd need some specialised equipment.

### Household wiring

If this system is also powering freezers, lights and fans the total current needed will be higher. You could probably not connect this system to a normal wall-outlet as the AC current might be high enough to blow the fuses, or if not, set fire to the wiring.

Systems like this probably need to be wired to the household main fusebox/distribution board using appropriate sized cables and protection etc.

Comment: There is a system available over there where they provide 1 battery an inverter and it just plugs into any existing socket and works for an hour or so if it just powers a couple of fans and a tv / laptop. I just want to magnify that power to do much more. The electricity shuts down there for between one and three hours and I want to be able to cover for this period. I was thinking about 4-6 batteries wired up in such a way as not to be dangerous. I wouldnt try before I got some good advice.

Comment: @saj: You should probably get advice from people in the place you will be staying. From my answer you should be able to see how to do the sums to calculate how many batteries you need. Take a fire extinguisher :-)